# ec2 instance ports 8080 and 8081not open

Tags: amazon-ec2, ports, netstat

I have an ubuntu instance ec2 and open Ports 8080 and 8081 from security group but my app give me connection lost and when I test open port via net stat -a give me open ports as shown in image below 
[image]

as you see port 8080 and 8081 not open.

please any help to fix this issue.

Comment: This means there is no service actually running to accept connections on these ports. What process do you expect to be listening on 8080 / 8081? Because it's not. Prehaps you meant to open 3000 / 3001 which are in-fact bound by a service?

Comment: I have app make connection to server via 8080 and 8081 now the app give me "connection lost" and also I cannot login to app admin panel

Comment: Maybe the server process has crashed? From the output, there is no process running on the server listening to those ports.

Comment: I run server.js file via nohup node server.js &

Comment: Check that the command is still running, I suspect you encountered an error and the script crashed, releasing the port binds.

Comment: when I run nohup node server.js & run all process but at the end give me[ 1]+  Exit 1                  nohup node server.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion - when creating Node or GoLang apps on EC2 that are intended to listen make sure you set their binding to the private EC2 instance IP Address and not the ELB IP.
The ELB IP is not available to the instance to bind to.
You can find the private IP in your AWS console.